# vscode ipynb how to accept user input

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using VS Code with Ipynb jupyter notebook.
How use input() command in vscode, this function works in jupyter, this function is also working iwth vs code , but freezes as it is waiting for user input.
Where or how can I/user input if using vs code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to have a bug when using `input()` without a string passed to it. 
Try using `input("Some string")`, a popup should appear to insert you input.

Comment: Thank you, reported it.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89302